# Why does the game speed fluctuate from slow to fast, and how do I prevent it?

Tags: technical-issues, terraria

When I play Terraria, the game speed will change while I am playing.  So sometimes it will be at "normal" speed, then it will dip into a slow speed, or a fast speed.  It seems the actual game updates are slower too, not just a dip in FPS.  For example, if I am mining I will collect more ore in the same amount of time if the game is sped up, and less if slower.

It doesn't seem to be controlled by anything going on in game, when there is a lot of things going on screen, it won't always go slower, and sometimes may go faster!

I have an AMD R9 290, intel i7 4770K, 16GB RAM.  Running Win10 now, but it happened on Win8.1 too.  This is in a single player game.  There is nothing else going on in the background.

What might cause this?  How do I prevent this?

Comment: Is this an online server? Is this single player? Is anything happening in the background (windows not terraria)?

Comment: Updated question.  Single player; nothing other than normal windows bs going on in the background.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to turn frame skip on. If you confirm this to work, I'll post this as an answer, as I don't like posting answers based on guessing.

Comment: Game speed fluctuating like that indicates that your PC can't handle what's going on and with frame skip off it can't skip frames to keep up, so it slows down and then has to catch up. The real question is - what else are you running in background that could be using that much processing power to slow down Terraria on that rig...

Comment: Frame skip has always been set to ON

Comment: In that case, have you tried turning it off?

Comment: try turning it off, and turning Vsync on (for terraria at least). Otherwise try deleting the config file in `my documents/my games/ terraria`

Comment: Hit F10 in game to see the FPS, let us know what FPS you are getting and if it increases/decreases when the game speeds up/slows down

Comment: Open task manager (`ctrl+shift+esc`) and monitor your cpu usage as the slowdowns occur.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the speed up, with the onscreen FPS enabled (F10) and I was able to see the frames the frames increase from 45 to 60.  I haven't reproduced the slow down.  Normal CPU usage for Terraria is ~17%, when the speed up occurs, it drops to ~9%

Comment: I've switched frame skip OFF, and already I see the baseline FPS is now 60, and the gameplay is what I called "sped up" before.  The CPU usage is now ~9% for the process.. no speed changes yet though.

Comment: Might be a power management issue and/or core parking. It seems odd that you only run at 45 fps normally and 60 is sped up, you should be able to run 60 at all times. Are you sure you're using your AMD R9 290 instead of the Intel HD4600? Do other games work fine?

Comment: what's the refresh rate of your monitor? 120?

Comment: Yeah, other games run perfectly. I can play much more intense games than this with no problem.

Comment: 60Hz for the monitor.  I think that turning the Frame Sync to off has solved the problem.  I haven't had any game speed fluctuations since I turned it off.  And it runs better with it off, oddly enough.

Comment: but it's still sped up right?

Comment: Yeah, at 60 FPS, which seems fine.  Obviously a bit faster than what I perceived was "normal" before, but not unplayable fast.

Comment: It is worth noting that FPS can easily effect how the rest of the game operates (mining for example) - however, this is a rookie mistake, from the developers point of view. Very unlikely, for terraria.

Comment: This is much more likely a performance issue than a bug. You can always check the Activity Monitor (MacOSX) to check your system’s performance (use Task Manager if you’re on a Windows machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one else is going to answer.

I turned the Frame Skip to OFF.   This not only seemed to cause a huge fluctuation in CPU usage and FPS, but also limited the base FPS to be at 45.

Tldr. Frame skip sucks, dont use it.